# installing Java via brew and cask

Tags: java, macos, homebrew, homebrew-cask

I just installed Java via `brew cask` on my mac.

```
brew cask install java8
```

It installed into `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_152.jdk/Contents/Home`.

I then set java home in my .zshrc file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
```

But when I type which java it shows.

```
/usr/bin/java -> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/Current/Commands/java
```

Does this correspond to the Java I just installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shell command search and the `which` command use the `PATH` environment variable, not `JAVA_HOME`. Unless there is something in your `.zshrc` that is setting the `PATH` based on `JAVA_HOME` then setting `JAVA_HOME` isn't going to have any impact on `which`.